# Is it possible somehow to find complex eigenvalues using SymPy?

Tags: python, sympy, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

I`m trying to write a program to operate with matrix, but when it comes to eigenvalues, i see this error:
"raise MatrixError(
sympy.matrices.common.MatrixError: Could not compute eigenvalues for Matrix([[5, -5, -3, 2, -7], [-2, -5, 0, 2, 1], [-2, -7, -5, -2, -6], [7, 10, 3, 9, -2], [4, -10, 3, -8, -4]]) "
I calculated those with Wolfram, and it appears to be that some of the eigenvalues are complex. Maybe that is the case?
Code below:

```
from sympy import *
A = Matrix([[5, -5, -3, 2, -7], [-2, -5, 0, 2, 1], [-2, -7, -5, -2, -6], [7, 10, 3, 9, -2], [4, -10, 3, -8, -4]])
A.eigenvals()
```

Comment: Replace the first `5` in `A` with `0j + 5` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, computing the [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial#Formal_definition) (which you can also get through the [charpoly method](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/matrices.html#sympy.matrices.matrices.MatrixDeterminant.charpoly) of a matrix object) and then finding the roots will work:

```py
from sympy import *
A = Matrix([[5, -5, -3, 2, -7], [-2, -5, 0, 2, 1], [-2, -7, -5, -2, -6], [7, 10, 3, 9, -2], [4, -10, 3, -8, -4]])
lam = symbols('\lambda')

char_poly = det(lam * eye(A.rows) - A)
roots_char_poly = solve(char_poly, lam)
display(char_poly)
display(roots(poly(char_poly, domain=CC)))
display([N(r) for r in roots_char_poly])
```

This is the result:

[image]

NOTES: I think what must be happening with the [eigenvals()](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/b6c328e2f057ba81513d19a1451ace358ecc8233/sympy/matrices/matrices.py#L367) method is there's some logic somewhere that guesses the charpoly's domain to be `Z[X]` when in fact it's `C[X]` (maybe because all of `A`'s elements are from `Z`.
Most likely either in [_eigenvals_dict](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/b6c328e2f057ba81513d19a1451ace358ecc8233/sympy/matrices/eigen.py#L209) or in [_eigenvals_list](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/b6c328e2f057ba81513d19a1451ace358ecc8233/sympy/matrices/eigen.py#L180) . Also the `error_when_incomplete` parameter is a bit unusual to me when looking [at the code](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/b6c328e2f057ba81513d19a1451ace358ecc8233/sympy/matrices/eigen.py#L193) especially because it's `True` by default.

Answer (score 0):

SymPy is trying to compute the eigenvalues exactly, and can't because it can't express the roots of the degree 5 characteristic polynomial. IMHO, this behavior should be improved (https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/20582), but for now, you can get floating point eigenvalues, if that's what you desire, by calling `evalf` on the matrix first.

```
>>> A.evalf().eigenvals()
{13.5753711727684 + 5.41544098000364e-64*I: 1, -3.67030896345605 - 7.25865117906282*I: 1, -8.34743023677284 - 3.67066417108162e-63*I: 1, 2.11267699091657 - 1.67049469057562e-63*I: 1, -3.67030896345605 + 7.25865117906282*I: 1}
```